# CppUnit test core dumped despite successful test. Why?

Tags: c++, cppunit

So I wanted to try TDD and set up CppUnit as test environment. I read the cookbook as I want to start small. I simply want to test a public factorial function of a class Factor. My test runs successfully but then the program suddenly core dumps and I have no idea why. I'm using g++ on Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit and CppUnit 1.14.

testmain.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"

int main(){

    CppUnit::TestCaller <Test1> test ("test", &Test1::testFactorial );

    CppUnit::TestSuite suite;
    suite.addTest(&test);

    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    runner.addTest(&suite);
    runner.run( );
    return 0;
}
```

test1.h

```
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H

#include <cppunit/TestAssert.h>
#include <cppunit/TestCase.h>
#include <cppunit/TestFixture.h>
#include <cppunit/TestCaller.h>
#include <cppunit/TestResult.h>
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/TestSuite.h>

#include "factorial.h"

class Test1 : public CppUnit::TestFixture {
private:
    Factor *f_6;

public:
    void setUp(){
        f_6 = new Factor();
    }

    void tearDown(){
        //to see whether my variable gets freed
        std::cout << "delete testvariable\n";
        delete f_6;
    }

    void testFactorial(){
        int f6 = f_6->factorial(6);
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT(f6 == 720);
    }
};

#endif
```

factorial.h

```
#ifndef FACTORIAL_H
#define FACTORIAL_H

class Factor{

public:
    int factorial(int arg){
        int result = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= arg; i++){
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }

};

#endif
```

Commandline Output:

```
user@computer:~/folder$ make test
g++ -g -Wall -o testexecutable testmain.cpp -lcppunit
user@computer:~/folder$ ./testexecutable 
.delete testvariable



OK (1 tests)


free(): invalid size
Aborted (core dumped)
user@computer:~/folder$
```

Why is there this weird free and core dump in the execution of the test case?

Comment: Print something also in setUp function to see if it is called properly.

Comment: Don't: `Factor *f_6;`. Use unique pointers instead. Less chance of such a memory corruption.

Comment: I tried getting unique_ptr and shared_ptr to work in a project a few months back for like two days before I gave up. I may use them somewhen in the future but for now I'd rather use stuff that works for me. If that's normal pointers and frees or deletes so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CppUnit test suites delete all the test objects in the destructor. So you need to allocate a test in your main, rather than using one directly on the stack.

Similarly I think a TestRunner also does a cleanup so you need to allocate the TestSuide object too.

See the "Suite" and "TestRunner" headings in:
http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html

Therefore your main becomes:

```
int main() {
    CppUnit::TestSuite* suite = new CppUnit::TestSuite();
    suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<Test1>("test", &Test1::testFactorial));
    CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    runner.addTest(suite);
    runner.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved it. It's pretty unintuitive for me since I'm used to call delete to every new I use but I guess it's better for automatic build systems. Anyway everything is working now. Have a good Sunday.